# Convert byte array pdf to actual document and read it

Tags: c#, pdf, devexpress, binaryfiles

I have a byte [], that I know it's a PDF, what I need to do now, it's to convert it to PDF format, so I can read it and check some lines inside of it?

How can I do this? I have access to DevExpress frameworks if its help.

Thanks

Comment: "to convert it to PDF format" - you said you know the `byte[]` contains the bytes of a PDF file, therefore it is already in the PDF file format. Are you asking how to write it to a file? Have you tried `File.WriteAllBytes`?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I need to make everything on client side, So yes I know that the `byte[]` it's already a PDF and I need to convert it from `byte[]` to an actual file and read some content inside of it.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I don't want to create an actual document on a folder, I want everything in memory or something like that if it's possible

Comment: Then you need a PDF library for .NET.  I think all the kool kids are using iTextSharp, though I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using [PdfViewer control](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraPdfViewer.PdfViewer).

This control has a method `LoadDocument` and one of the [overloads](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraPdfViewer.PdfViewer.LoadDocument(System.IO.Stream)) accepts stream a parameter.
So you can create a [MemoryStream from the array](https://learn.microsoft.com/sl-si/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-io-memorystream-ctor(system-byte())) and load this stream into your PdfViewer.

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(mybytearray);
pdfViewer1.LoadDocument(ms);
```

**UPDATE:**

You should use [PdfDocumentProcessor](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/DevExpress.Pdf.PdfDocumentProcessor).
This class has a method `LoadDocument` and one of the [overloads](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/DevExpress.Pdf.PdfDocumentProcessor.LoadDocument(System.IO.Stream)) accepts stream as a parameter.
So you can create a [MemoryStream from the array](https://learn.microsoft.com/sl-si/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-io-memorystream-ctor(system-byte())) and load this stream into your PdfDocumentProcessor.

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(mybytearray);
pdfDocumentProcessor1.LoadDocument(ms);
```

Then you can access the content of the document. For example you can use [GetText](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/DevExpress.Pdf.PdfDocumentProcessor.GetText) method.

Comment: Then how can read its content?

Comment: What do you mean with reading?

Comment: Oh, I get it now. You want to read data from code, not with you eyes. I've updated the answer.